# Is windows.h still relevant in nowadays developing enviroment?

Tags: windows, api

Hi I am a computer science student. and my question is this:
let's put aside windows forms for a second and java.
is windows.h header used in C programming language alone, still relevant today
for creating windows_based applications. (with windows, graphics, so on) in a way that is good enough for modern product design ?
If so, can you link me to websites with projects based on windows.h ?

Thank You (:

Comment: It's relevant if you're programming for Win32.  There's still a lot of that going on.  If you're not doing that, then it might not be relevant to you.  Similar to if your car(s) are electric, spark plugs might not be relevant anymore to you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in that comment.

Comment: I mean that there is still a lot of programming to the Win32 API for Windows programs.  It's not as dominate as in the past, but it's not gone.  If you want to program against the Windows Win32 API, then the `windows.h` header will probably be relevant to you.  If you're programming in Java or for Apple iOS devices, then it probably won't.  If you're asking if you should learn Win32 programming, then that's a different question (and one that I can't answer).

Comment: You'll know it when you need it, you are not there yet.  Plenty of links, [this is one](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).

Comment: Got it (: thank you.